# Definition of $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, definition

The following is an excerpt of Serre's book on finite groups. I am very confused by his definition of the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$. Why does he take $ad-bc$ a *non-zero square*? The definition I know is the quotient of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ by $\{I,-I \}$.

Why is the fractional linear transformation $t:i\mapsto 2i$ an element of $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$? It seems that this one has determinant $2$?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please don't rely on images of text. They're difficult to search.

Comment: Officially, $SL_2(\mathbb F_7)$ consists of matrices with determinant $1$. Serre allows the determinant to be a square, say $k^2$, other than $1$, because, dividing each matrix entry by $k$, one can convert such a matrix to one whose determinant is $1$ without changing the associated fractional linear transformation.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I am afraid I don't understand, could you elaborate? For example, $k\mapsto 2k$  has determinant 2 right?

Comment: @Dr.HeinzDoofenshmirtz $k\mapsto 2k$ can also be written as $k\mapsto\frac{4k+0}{0k+2}$.

Comment: @user10354138 ah yes of course, how could I have overlooked that. Thanks!±